# Problem using GEKKO to do estimate time-varying variable using APOPT solver in combination with integer=True

Tags: gekko

Using GEKKO Python, we have trouble trying to learn an integer variable that can vary multiple times per day. In some disciplines this is also known as 'regime detection or regime change detection'.
Based on an [earlier stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75237837/problem-using-gekko-to-do-regime-change-detection-estimating-time-varying-varia) we are now able to get results for predicting time-varying float variables. However, when trying to predict integer values using `integer= True` and m.options.SOLVER=1 (i.e. use the APOPT solver, as suggested in a [comment on the earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75237837/problem-using-gekko-to-do-regime-change-detection-estimating-time-varying-varia#comment133647459_75280759), we still don't get a solution.

(we = me and my colleague Hossein Rahmani from Windesheim University of Applied Sciences)

Our question(s) is: What are we doing wrong, is there an obvious error in our GEKKO code (more below in the details)?

Your help is much appreciated.

---

The problem: We have time series data about:
(1) CO₂ concentration
(2) ventilation rates (or rather: valve fractions, which give ventilation rates, when multiplied with known maximum ventilation rates)
(3) occupancy (number of persons in a room)

For our research question we would like to know a proper estimate for occupancy for each hour of the day, given time series data about CO₂ concentration and ventilation rates.
We considered occupancy and valve_fraction as a Manipulated Variable in our Gekko model (m.MV) while the difference is occupancy can be "adjusted by the optimizer to minimize an objective function at every time point" while valve_fraction is specified by the user (measured data). According to Gekko documentation, only APOPT solver (m.option.SOLVER=1) is able to predict integer values for variables which is used in our model.
N.B. The [csv data used in the code below can be viewed here](https://github.com/energietransitie/twomes-inverse-grey-box-analysis/blob/main/data/B4B_virtual_ds/virtual_dataset_P100010045.csv); the code actually uses the [raw data available here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/energietransitie/twomes-inverse-grey-box-analysis/main/data/B4B_virtual_ds/virtual_dataset_P100010045.csv)

Below the code that can be used to reproduce the problem

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pytz
from gekko import GEKKO


# room id; for virtual rooms, various constants are encoded in the id
id = 100010045
github_url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com'
github_org = 'energietransitie'
github_path = 'main/data/B4B_virtual_ds'
repo = 'twomes-inverse-grey-box-analysis'

# Create a timezone object for Europe/Amsterdam
tz = pytz.timezone('Europe/Amsterdam')

df_learn =  (pd.read_csv(f'{github_url}/{github_org}/{repo}/{github_path}/virtual_dataset_P{id}.csv', 
                        parse_dates=['timestamp'])\
             .set_index('timestamp')
             .tz_convert(tz, level='timestamp')
            )

learn_streak_period_start = df_learn.index.get_level_values('timestamp').min()
learn_streak_period_end = df_learn.index.get_level_values('timestamp').max()
learn_streak_period_len = len(df_learn)

step__s = ((learn_streak_period_end - learn_streak_period_start).total_seconds()
          /
          (learn_streak_period_len-1)
         )

duration__s = step__s * learn_streak_period_len


#select column names
property_sources = {
    'co2__ppm' : 'model_co2__ppm',           # options: ['bms_co2__ppm', 'CO2-meter-SCD4x_co2__ppm', 'model_co2__ppm']
    'occupancy__p': 'model_occupancy__p',    # options: ['CO2-meter-SCD4x_occupancy__p', 'xovis_occupancy__p','model_occupancy__p']
    'valve_frac__0': 'model_valve_frac__0'   # options: ['bms_occupancy__p', 'bms_occupancy__bool', 'model_valve_frac__0']
}


hints = {
    'A_inf__m2' : (10 / 1e4) # 10 [cm^2] 
}
    
#select whether to learn a time-varying parameters as well (NB you can set 0 or 1 of these to true, both not both
learn = [
    'A_inf__m2',
    # 'valve_frac__0',
    'occupancy__p',
]

m = GEKKO(remote = False)
m.time = np.arange(0, duration__s, step__s)


# Conversion factors
s_min_1 = 60                                                  # [s] per [min]
min_h_1 = 60                                                  # [min] per [h]
s_h_1 = s_min_1 * min_h_1                                     # [s] per [h]
ml_m_3 = 1e3 * 1e3                                            # [ml] per [m^3]
umol_mol_1 = 1e6                                              # [µmol] per [mol]
cm2_m_2 = 1e2 * 1e2                                           # [cm^2] per [m^2]
O2ml_min_1_kg_1_p_1_MET_1 = 3.5                               # [mlO₂‧kg^-1‧min^-1] per [MET] 

# Constants
desk_work__MET = 1.5                                          # Metabolic Equivalent of Task for desk work [MET]
P_std__Pa = 101325                                            # standard gas pressure [Pa]
R__m3_Pa_K_1_mol_1 = 8.3145                                   # gas constant [m^3⋅Pa⋅K^-1⋅mol^-1)]
temp_room__degC = 20.0                                        # standard room temperature [°C]
temp_std__degC = 0.0                                          # standard gas temperature [°C]
temp_zero__K = 273.15                                         # 0 [°C] = 273.15 [K]
temp_std__K = temp_std__degC + temp_zero__K                   # standard gas temperature [K]
temp_room__K = temp_room__degC + temp_zero__K                 # standard room temperature [K]

# Approximations
air__mol_m_3 = (P_std__Pa
                 / (R__m3_Pa_K_1_mol_1 * temp_room__K)
                )                                             # molar quantity of an ideal gas under room conditions [mol⋅m^-3]
std__mol_m_3 = (P_std__Pa 
                / (R__m3_Pa_K_1_mol_1 * temp_std__K)
               )                                              # molar quantity of an ideal gas under standard conditions [mol⋅m^-3] 

metabolism__molCO2_molO2_1 = 0.894                            # ratio: moles of CO₂ produced by (aerobic) human metabolism per mole of O₂ consumed 

# National averages
co2_ext_2022__ppm = 415                                       # Yearly average CO₂ concentration in Europe in 2022
weight__kg = 77.5                                             # average weight of Dutch adult [kg]
umol_s_1_p_1_MET_1 = (O2ml_min_1_kg_1_p_1_MET_1
                   * weight__kg
                   / s_min_1 
                   * (umol_mol_1 * std__mol_m_3 / ml_m_3)
                   )                                          # molar quantity of O₂inhaled by an average Dutch adult at 1 MET [µmol/(p⋅s)]
co2_exhale__umol_p_1_s_1 = (metabolism__molCO2_molO2_1
                            * desk_work__MET
                            * umol_s_1_p_1_MET_1
                           )                                  # molar quantity of CO₂ exhaled by Dutch desk worker doing desk work [µmol/(p⋅s)]

# Virtual room constants
co2_ext__ppm = co2_ext_2022__ppm                      # Average CO₂ concentration in Europe in 2022, used for model 
wind__m_s_1 = 3.0                                     # modeled wind speed for virtual rooms, causing infiltration
room__m3 = id % 1e3                                   # room air volume is encoded in the last 3 positions of the room id
vent_min__m3_h_1 = (id % 1e6) // 1e3                  # minimum ventilation (caused by wind) is encoded in the middle 3 positions of the room id
vent_max__m3_h_1 = id // 1e6                          # maximum ventilation (when valve_frac__0 = 1.0) is encoded in the first 3 positions of the room id
actual_A_inf__m2 = vent_min__m3_h_1 / (s_h_1 * wind__m_s_1)
vent_max__m3_s_1 = vent_max__m3_h_1 / s_h_1

# GEKKO time-varying variables: measured values or learned
if 'occupancy__p' in learn:
    occupancy__p = m.MV(value = df_learn[property_sources['occupancy__p']].astype('float32').values, lb=0, ub=12, integer=True)
    occupancy__p.STATUS = 1; occupancy__p.FSTATUS = 0
else:
    occupancy__p = m.MV(value = df_learn[property_sources['occupancy__p']].astype('float32').values)
    occupancy__p.STATUS = 0; occupancy__p.FSTATUS = 1

if 'valve_frac__0' in learn:
    valve_frac__0 = m.MV(value = df_learn[property_sources['valve_frac__0']].values, lb=0, ub=1)
    valve_frac__0.STATUS = 1; valve_frac__0.FSTATUS = 0
else:
    valve_frac__0 = m.MV(value = df_learn[property_sources['valve_frac__0']].values)
    valve_frac__0.STATUS = 0; valve_frac__0.FSTATUS = 1

# GEKKO time-independent variables: approximated or learned
if 'A_inf__m2' in learn:
    A_inf__m2 = m.FV(value = hints['A_inf__m2'], lb = 0)
    A_inf__m2.STATUS = 1; A_inf__m2.FSTATUS = 0
else:
    A_inf__m2 = hints['A_inf__m2']  

# GEKKO Control Varibale (predicted variable for which fit is optimized)
co2__ppm = m.CV(value = df_learn[property_sources['co2__ppm']].values) #[ppm]
co2__ppm.STATUS = 1; co2__ppm.FSTATUS = 1

# GEKKO - Equations
co2_elevation__ppm = m.Intermediate(co2__ppm - co2_ext__ppm)
co2_loss_vent__ppm_s_1 = m.Intermediate(co2_elevation__ppm * vent_max__m3_s_1 * valve_frac__0 / room__m3)
co2_loss_inf__ppm_s_1 = m.Intermediate(co2_elevation__ppm * wind__m_s_1 * A_inf__m2 / room__m3)
co2_loss__ppm_s_1 = m.Intermediate(co2_loss_vent__ppm_s_1 + co2_loss_inf__ppm_s_1)
co2_gain__ppm_s_1 = m.Intermediate(occupancy__p * co2_exhale__umol_p_1_s_1 / (room__m3 * air__mol_m_3))
m.Equation(co2__ppm.dt() == co2_gain__ppm_s_1 - co2_loss__ppm_s_1)

# GEKKO - Solver setting
m.options.IMODE = 5
m.options.EV_TYPE = 2 # specific objective function (1 = MAE; 2 = RMSE)
m.options.NODES = 2                              
m.options.SOLVER = 1        #(APOPT Solver; this does not seem to work; we get @error: Solution Not Found)
# m.options.SOLVER = 3      #(IPOPT Solver; this seems to work, but learned occupancy__p values are not integers)
m.solve(disp = True)
```

As already hinted in the in the code comments, the APOPT solver, which is the solver suggested to be used when using `integer=True` for a manipulated variable, does NOT find a solution, and the IPOPT solver changing the last lines of code to the code below, DOES find a solution (but it ignores the `integer=True` instructions).

```py
# m.options.SOLVER = 1      #(APOPT Solver; this does not seem to work; we get @error: Solution Not Found)
m.options.SOLVER = 3        #(IPOPT Solver; this seems to work, but learned occupancy__p values are not integers)
m.solve(disp = True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problems with integer variables are generally much more difficult to solve than problems with continuous variables.

From the [Dynamic Optimization Course](https://apmonitor.com/do/index.php/Main/DiscreteVariables) (and with a few mixed-integer example problems):

> At first glance it might seem solving a discrete variable problem
> would be easier than a continuous problem. After all, for a variable
> within a given range, a set of discrete values within the range is
> finite whereas the number of continuous values is infinite. When
> searching for an optimum, it seems it would be easier to search from a
> finite set rather than from an infinite set.
>
> This is not the case, however. Solving discrete problems is harder
> than continuous problems. This is because of the combinatorial
> explosion that occurs in all but the smallest problems. For example if
> we have two variables which can each take 10 values, we have 10*10 =
> 100 possibilities. If we have 10 variables that can each take 10
> values, we have 10^10 possibilities. Even with the fastest computer,
> it would take a long time to evaluate all of these.

APOPT uses a branch and bound method to solve problems more efficiently than an exhaustive search, but the repeated solution of many NLP problems takes much longer than a single NLP solution. The comment on the prior question was probably a mistake. I'd recommend using a continuous variable on the occupancy of a building. My guess is that 27.3 reveals just as much information as 27 or 28 occupants because the sensors are not sufficiently accurate to exactly estimate the number of occupants.

APOPT can be configured to ignore `integer=True` designations:

```py
m.solver_options = ['minlp_as_nlp 1']
```

or just leave off the `integer=True` when declaring the occupancy variable.

Comment: Great, this answer helped us a lot!